# compare all data in two tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables and I want to compare all the values for all columns except for col 4 in table 2 and check whether the data matches or not.

**Table 1**

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

**Table 2**

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 8 |

Is there any way to solve it in laravel? Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't recall a built-in way to achieve this. But you can write any PHP code you like.

Comment: can you share an example for that ?

Comment: Well you would query both tables and compare them in a loop. I don't think I have time to write a solution for you.

Comment: There's many ways to do this. What would most likely work is the one that best fits your existing code and where you need to use this so do share some more context as well as show us at least an indication that you tried to solve this problem yourself

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: i have tried to break the columns into array and then i am comapring  their values 

```
 $weight_charges = WeightCharge::where('user_id',$id);
        $standard_charges = StandardWeightCharge::where('shipping_mode_id',1);
        if($weight_charges->where('shipping_mode_id',1)->exists()){
            $standard_range_up = $standard_charges->pluck('range_up')->toArray();
            $weight_range_up = $weight_charges->where('shipping_mode_id',1)->pluck('range_up')->toArray();
            $weight_range_up_diff_1 = $this->compare_data($weight_range_up,$standard_range_up);
```

Comment: this is my static function 

static public function compare_data($array_2,$array_1){
        if(count($array_2) == count($array_1)){
            $diff = array_diff($array_2,$array_1);
            if(count($diff) > 0){
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }

        }
        else{
            return 1;
        }
    }

if it returns 1 that menas thier is a change

Answer (score 1):

If the first table called `books` with `Book` model and the second table called `book_copies` with `BookCopy` model, you could try the following:

```
$books = Book::select('col1', 'col2', 'col3')->get();
$bookCopies = BookCopy::select('col1', 'col2', 'col3')->get();
return $books->diffAssoc($bookCopies)->isEmpty();
```

Comment: got the following error when tried your method        The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.